# PHP SHA-256 check sum in base64 to match that of Java

Tags: java, php, sha

I have java program which calculates SHA-256 checksum as follows. For example, if I provide the input **abcd123ABCD00-4000** it outputs **0QtyIu4B+lU+TLqM/zfJz5ULVpyXgfLRs5mKXCQvbHM=** . It also matches the [online check sum calculator](http://hash.online-convert.com/sha256-generator).

However the PHP code I used won't match it.

PHP code :

```
$s = 'abcd123ABCD00-4000';
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $s, True)); 
print  base64_encode($signature);
```

Output : TWpRM1pEWXpaVFl4TURoallqTXdPRFV6WVRrNU5XVTRNRGxoWkRJMU1XWTVNREk1TnpBeU4ySXhaR0psTW1ZMk16Y3hPRE01WldFelkySXhOalJrWXc9PQ==

Java Code :

```
private static String getSHA256Hash(String text) {


    String hash = null;
    MessageDigest md = null;


    try {

      md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

      md.update(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));

      byte[] shaDig = md.digest();
      // hash = Hex.encodeHexString(shaDig);
      hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(shaDig);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return hash;

  }
```

Output : 0QtyIu4B+lU+TLqM/zfJz5ULVpyXgfLRs5mKXCQvbHM=

Here what I want is to get the equivalent result in PHP (i.e to change PHP code to match result of the Java program[ I won't able to change the Java code ]. Any help is appreciated

Comment: hash_hmac is not the same as a normal sha256 hash!

Comment: hmm, learned it hard way !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[If you use hash() and base64 encode **once** you get the same result.](http://3v4l.org/8QcsF)

```
$s = 'abcd123ABCD00-4000';
$signature = base64_encode(hash("sha256", $s, True)); 
print  $signature; // 0QtyIu4B+lU+TLqM/zfJz5ULVpyXgfLRs5mKXCQvbHM=
```